# Dynamically change element's Index

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to make something like this:

I press on the button and the window pops up, now this window's Index would be 1, if I press the other button the new window (div element) would appear but its index would be 2.

Now I have the function - click which sets the index using the global Index variable and at the end of my function, I increase Index variable. But I am failing to get results - the Index variable is not increasing (it's increasing only then I am clicking on the same button). Any solutions?

code:
HTML

```
<div @click="open(file.name)" class="folder">
    <div class="folder-styling">


    <div :style="{ 'background-image': 'url(/img/' + file.icon + '.png)' }" class="folder-icon">

    </div>
    <p>{{file.name}}</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
        open(folder){


       var doc = document.getElementById(folder)
       doc.style.zIndex = this.$index+1
       var tab = document.getElementById('tabs'+folder)
       doc.style.display = "block",

       tab.style.display = "inline-block",
       this.$props.file.active(true)
       this.index = this.$index + 1
       console.log(this.$index)


    }
```

Global variable inside main.js file:

```
Vue.prototype.$index = 1
```